# While launching Hive I'm getting this error - log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HiveEventCounter]

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu, hadoop, hive, bigdata

log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HiveEventCounter].

[image]

Comment: Did you check compability of your hive and hadoop version. That sounds like compability issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced JAVA11 with JAVA8, and it worked.